# Extract matching Values in Excel IF Statement

Tags: excel, vlookup

I currently have the following dataset

[image]

A company is given as company number, each row represents a time they have used a service, values are only given as 1 == success and 0 == failure.

So in the case of Company 1 > it used Service 1 - only 1 time

however this where i need help

For company 1 on the 3rd row, it used Service 2 and Service 3 only once, this is an error in the dataset, i want this to only read Service 2 as 1 and Service 3 as 0

This occurs within the entire dataset and the condition is the same every time 
if the number 1 exists for a row in Service 2 and Service 3, then make Service 2 have the value 1 and service 3 have the value 0

Do you guys have any info on how i could add a column at the end called "correct service2" which contains the correct value of 1's?

I know it involves an IF statement but i am super stuck

Comment: Would it not be `Correct Service 3`, as that is the one you want to change?

Comment: nope - i want to only keep the 1's in the service 3 column

Comment: Your words above: `i want this to only read Service 2 as 1 and Service 3 as 0`

Comment: and : `then make Service 2 have the value 1 and service 3 have the value 0`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A1 = company number

in H2 :

```
=if(sum(C2:G2)=1,"OK","notOK")
```

and drag downwards.